# Data not updating on array

Tags: javascript, node.js

I tried this http endpoint to update data on array call userArr, But any data wouldn't be updated

```
app.put('/update/:Id',function (req, res) {

try{
const index = userArr.findIndex(instence => instence.id == req.params.Id);
userArr[index].firstName = req.body.fName;
userArr[index].lastName = req.body.lName;
userArr[index].birthDay = req.body.bDay;
res.status(200).send(userArr[index]);
}catch(e){
res.status(500).send({message:e});
}
```

Expected output is status 200 actual output is 500

Comment: What is the error message apart from status code 500?

Answer (score 0):

Thats because you are not sending the Id value to the API call. You are sending the string 'ID'
It should be like

```
var Id = "your id value";
app.put('/update/:'+ Id,function (req, res) {

try{
const index = userArr.findIndex(instence => instence.id == req.params.Id);
userArr[index].firstName = req.body.fName;
userArr[index].lastName = req.body.lName;
userArr[index].birthDay = req.body.bDay;
res.status(200).send(userArr[index]);
}catch(e){
res.status(500).send({message:e});
}
```